# matching URL parameter spanning multiple "/" in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

What is the best way to match URL parameter spanning multiple "/" in ASP.NET MVC ?

Eg URL: http://example.com/controller/action/p1/p2/p3/p4

I want to pass just one parameter to the action method (above, it is "p1/p2/p3/p4"). Here, the parameter may have arbitrary number of subitems ( p1/.../pn ).

What is the best way to accomplish this? Any way to get this implemented using pure MVC routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand it clearly you want to make it this way

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}/{*p}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string p)
    {
        string[] parameters = p.Split('/');
        //Whatever
    }
}
```

Or you can do it with regex, you may take a look this [link](http://www.iridescence.no/post/Defining-Routes-using-Regular-Expressions-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx)